# Change one dataframe values to another based on a condition and when they have different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = {'Yes/No': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No'], 'ID': [11, 22, 33, 44], 'Expiration': ['2023', '2022', '2022', '2024'], 'Code': ['B11', 'A11', 'D11', 'C11'], 'Number': [303, 202, 301, 222]}

df2 = {'Yes_No': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes'], 'ExpiryDate': ['2026', '2027', '2028'], 'UniqueCode': ['A22', 'B11', 'C11']}
```

I want to update the first dataframe's Yes/No and Expiration columns with the Yes_No and ExpiryDate cols of d2 respectively, where the Number value is either 303 or 301 and Code value is equal to UniqueCode value of df2.

So the updated df1 would look like:

```
df1 = {'Yes/No': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'], 'ID': [11, 22, 33, 44], 'Expiration': ['2023', '2027', '2028', '2024'], 'Code': ['A11', 'B11', 'C11', 'D11'], 'Number': [303, 202, 301, 222]}
```

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
df1['Yes/No'] = np.where(((df1['Number'] == 301) | (df1['Number'] == 303)) & df1['Code'] == df2['UniqueCode'], df2['Yes_No'], df1['Yes/No'])
df1['Expiration'] = np.where(((df1['Number'] == 301) | (df1['Number'] == 303)) & df1['Code'] == df2['UniqueCode'], df2['ExpiryDate'], df1['Expiration'])
```

or like this:

```
df1['Yes/No'] = np.where(((df1['Number'] == 301) | (df1['Number'] == 303)) & df1['Code'] == df2['UniqueCode'], df2['Yes_No'], df1['Yes/No'])
df1['Expiration'] = np.where(((df1['Number'] == 301) | (df1['Number'] == 303)) & df1['Code'] == df2['UniqueCode'], df2['ExpiryDate'], df1['Expiration'])
```

but I'm getting:
"Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" in the first case and "ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare" in the second.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok - HOWEVER, it cannot be used with criteria in two different dataframes in the same line of code.
Therefore, you need to merge to one dataframe before:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Code', right_on='UniqueCode')
```

And then your code:

```
df1['Yes/No'] = np.where(((df1['Number'] == 301) | (df1['Number'] == 303)) & df1['Code'] == df1['UniqueCode'], df1['Yes_No'], df1['Yes/No'])
df1['Expiration'] = np.where(((df1['Number'] == 301) | (df1['Number'] == 303)) & df1['Code'] == df1['UniqueCode'], df1['ExpiryDate'], df1['Expiration'])
```

Refering to df1 only